# Can anyone decrypt files when 2 copies present on EncFS?

Tags: linux, encryption, encfs

Can anyone clarify this conclusion in the audit on EncFS:

'EncFS is probably safe as long as the adversary only gets one copy of the ciphertext and nothing more. EncFS is not safe if the adversary has the opportunity to see two or more snapshots of the ciphertext at different times. EncFS attempts to protect files from malicious modification, but there are serious problems with this feature.'

The question is: when would anybody get 2 copies of the cyphertext? Is that when you copy 2 of the same files (same sizes) with a different name. And what is the risk?

What I want to be sure of, is that individual files cannot be read (decrypted)... I'm not worried about modification...

Answer (score 0):

I think the "snapshots" of the ciphertext at different times is referring to someone copying an encrypted file before & after it's been modified by you somehow, otherwise just copying an unmodified file twice should give you two identical copies.

If someone copies all your encrypted files one day, then comes back a week later after you've modified some files and copies them all again, they'll have two copies of the ciphertext.

I think the theory is that if they can see how the file is modified, it would give them some clue about how to modify the file themselves (maliciously). I don't think they'll be able to decrypt any files, but maybe modify some so they're not immediately noticed - they'd most likely appear to you (decrypted) as corrupted.

I'm not aware of all the potential risks, maybe eventually after seeing enough files modified it would give a clue about how to decrypt all the files, but I've never heard of that actually being done successfully, and  I don't think there's any real risk of the files being decrypted from seeing two copies of ciphertext.

---

There would be a real risk of the non-encrypted (system) files being modified maliciously (to record keystrokes or store encryption keys, monitor all activity, etc) if someone has access to your computer, or even installing physical keyloggers or screen monitors if they have physical access. I'd say that's a far far greater threat than ever having EncFS decrypted.